# Wrapping uneditable Singleton classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I have `SingletonA` and `SingletonB`, classes in an obfuscated jarfile. They do not implement the same interface nor are they children of the same superclass, but they do have similar characteristics, which the original programmers missed.

I want to be able to pass them as arguments to a method like this:

```
public void method(SingletonObject singleton) {
    //do stuff with singleton
}
```

However, the only thing I can think of that would work is this:

```
    public void method(Object singleton) {     
        if(singleton instanceof SingletonA) {
           SingletonA singletonA = (SingletonA) singleton;
            // do stuff with singletonA
        }
        else if(singleton instanceof SingletonB) {
            SingletonB singletonB = (SingletonB) singleton;
           //do exact same stuff with singletonB
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Since the bottom example is terrible, what can I do to make it look more like the top.

Comment: If the singleton is small and the use cases many, then you can create a wrapper that externally has the shared properties, but under the hood can make the decision about what type of singleton it wraps.  But if the singleton is large and the use cases few, your current method is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that a certain method exists for these 2 different classes, then you can use reflection

```
  public void method(Object singleton) {
        Class<?> clazz = singleton.getClass();
        Method m;
        try {
            m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("someCommonMethod");
            //m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(singleton);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

Comment: And reflection saves the day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Composition also could be an option:

```
class SingletonObject{
     SingletonA a;
     SingletonB b;

    SingletonObject(SingletonA a, SingletonB b){
         if(a==null && b==null){
            throw InvalidArgumentException();
         }
       this.a = a;
       this.b =b
    }    

    public void callCommonMethod(){
         if(a!=null){
            a.callCommonMethod();
         }else{
           b.callCommonMethod()
         }
    }
}
```

so you composed singleton objects in one class where anyone can used it without know how is behind them